# UIImagePickerController return image nil when allowEditing = NO; and run on iPad as 2x

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
- (IBAction) buttonAction:(id) sender {
 if (self.picker == nil) {   
        self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.picker.delegate = self;
        self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        self.picker.allowsEditing = NO;     }  [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:_picker
    animated:YES];
```

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  ```
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

  UIImage *myImage = (UIImage *) [info
  objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; 

   if (myImage == nil) NSLog(@"Image nil");

  }
  ```

It's work fine on iPhone device but it's does'nt work on iPad at iPhone 2x mode
Bugs?
Or I'm wrong?

Comment: This odd situation is happening to me in iOS 9.2, on a Retina iPad (3rd gen), and in an iPad-only app, and only with images picked from the Library. The Camera works just fine. Using `allowsEditing = YES` returns an image, but at twice the size it should be and cropped to the upper-left.